# How do i fix the linting on brackets?

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

Starting off using brackets as a text editor to write javascript code, kindly note I'm a beginner, and I'm getting weird errors when I write my code like `unexpected console statement` when I use `console.log()` or `name is not defined` if I declare a variable called name. How can I disable that feature or edit its code to fix these messages.

**Edit:**

What i wrote:

```
var name = "john";
var age = 26;
console.log(age)
var job,ismarried;
ismarried = true;
```

I'm getting xs sign near my lines although the age is showing in chrome normally so the issue isn't with that very simple code it's with the text editor and I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Could you share some code with us that way we can help you

Comment: Give an example of a statement you wrote that gave you an error, then we can fix it. We can't fix something we don't know.

Comment: The issue isn't with the code it's with the text editor it has a feature that's making life hard:) kindly refer to my edit, thank you.

Comment: Which text editor do you use?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question and the tag it's `brackets` was better off with another but the instructor recommended this one.

Comment: If you see the tag description, it literally says "DO NOT USE THIS for the IDE, use [adobe-brackets] instead".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My instructor's answer:

These errors are probably related to `JSLint` and/or `ESLint`. These are tools used in Brackets to scan your code for bugs.You can also disable `JSLint`. To do that: Go to `Brackets > File > Extension Manager > Default > Disable ESLint and JSLint`.

Comment: Actually you're missing a `;` at the end of `console.log(age)` that's why your linter is spitting out a error

Answer (score 0):

for error like "unexpected console statement [no-console]" in brackets

Click on "Debug" in on your toolbar.
In the dropdown, click on "Open Preferences File".

and add below line in the brackets.json file

```
"language": {
      "javascript": {
          "linting.prefer": ["JSHint"],
          "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
      }
  }
```

link for the same : 
https://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/brackets-editor-disable-jslint-and-use-jshint-instead-2/